# First ASP.NET webpage launches without debugging, doesn't launch with debugging

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, iis, iis-express

Did anyone encounter an error with ASP.NET debugging? I've made a really simple, empty MVC page, I've tried returning /Home/Index.cshtml and a string, and each time I get a windows jingle and the browser can't find the server. It doesn't happen when I run it without debugging though, then the website runs just fine.
I've also tried the default MVC template, with Bootstrap etc, and it's the same - runs without debugging, doesn't run with debugging.

It's probably important: I'm running Visual Studio 2017 on up-to-date Windows 10. I've reinstalled the system several weeks ago, really wouldn't want to do that again :/

Comment: What I've figured out so far on my own is, there's a problem with attaching a debugger to IIS Express - there's an error stating that when I try to launch ASP.Net Core app.

Comment: Whether this issue has been resolved? If not, what is the error you got in your side? Do you debug your app in debug mode? Do you enable the ASP.NET under project property->web->Debugger?

Comment: Jack thanks for your suggestion, I do have enabled ASP.NET debugging, I tried both debug and release. There's no error, I just hear a Windows error jingle playing, the browser tab opens and after some time says it can't find the server.
I've resolved the issue for now by opening Visual Studio as admin, then it works fine, but I'm still curious about this issue.

Comment: Glad to know that it works well, I add the comment as the answer and provide the possible reasons for this issue. If possible, you could check it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally we could debug an app with the normal user, but sometimes we need to use the admin, for example, as far as I know, if we want to use the attach to process tool for remote debugging, we often run the VS as the admin or others.

This document share us the tasks we need administrator permissions to complete：

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj662724.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

If possible, you could refer to it especially "Debugging" area in above link.

Hope it could help you:)